# using Filter / Elem on Lazy Byte Strings in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am attempting to scrape a web site using the Scalpel Library and have returned a list of byte strings that I am having trouble filtering on.

I have a list of Lazy Byte Strings, for example:

```
 ["<a href=\"?ep=17&amp;fmt=0\">Jerk</a>", "<a href=\"?fmt=0&amp;yr=1997\" onmouseover=\"img_hov('t1997')\" onmouseout=\"img_norm('t1997')\"><img src=\"image/1997.gif\" alt=\"1997\" width=\"84\" height=\"43\" name=\"t1997\" border=\"0\"></a>"]
```

and I want to filter this list to find only the lazy byte strings that contain 'ep='

I also need to have the & symbol in the string not &amp

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you're saying about `&` vs. `&amp`. Can you expand on that? Also, how did you come to have this list of lazy `ByteString`s? Does it really make sense for them to be lazy?

Answer (score 1):

The usual `filter` is great for filtering lists. Use it! Unfortunately, the `bytestring` package doesn't offer nice tools for finding arbitrary substrings of lazy `ByteString`s, though it does offer such for strict ones. The authors may have decided that it was too hard to make those functions work efficiently in the lazy case. It might be easiest to convert each lazy `ByteString` to either a strict `ByteString` or a `String` and then use the tools in `Data.ByteString` or `Data.List` to perform the search. It's pretty hard to understand what you're getting at regarding `&amp;`, so you'll have to clarify.

Comment: "*The authors may have decided that it was too hard to make those functions work efficiently in the lazy case."* Well, given that a lazy bytestring is more or less a `[Strict.ByteString]`, that's likely.

Comment: @Zeta, yes, but it feels like abdication of their librarianly duties. They, not users, should consider the various implementation techniques and choose the best (for general use). I'd think it best to offer one function for finding a strict `ByteString` within a lazy one, and another to find a lazy one within a lazy one.